# Como faço para o text-overflow: ellipsis não influenciar a imagem

Tags: css

Estou tentando criar um Leia mais no meu site, só que quando coloco text-overflow: ellipsis não aparece as reticencias e ele começa a cortar a imagem.

```
.blog-home-content {

clear: both;
height: 100px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
width: 200px;    /* largura da imagem */
text-overflow: ellipsis;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
}



.blog-home-content img{

width: 200px;    /* largura da imagem */
height: 100px;   /*  altura da imagem  */
margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}
```

---

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfYbB.png Ele tá assim, cortando a letra e não mostrando as reticencias, quero que ele mostre as reticencias. (de preferencia com no máximo 3 linhas)

```
foreach ($get_blog->get_blog_posts($per_page2, $lang_blog_more) as $post) {
echo "<div class='blog-home-entry'>\n";
echo "<h2 class='blog-title'><a href=\"blog-$post[0]-$post[3]\">$post[5]</a></h2>\n"; 
echo "<div class='blog-date'>".date($order, strtotime($post[2]))."</div>\n";


if ($blog_comments) {               
     echo "<div class='num_comments'><a href=\"blog-$post[0]-$post[3]#comments\">";
     if ($post[1]) { echo "($post[1]) $lang_blog_num_comment"; } else { echo $lang_blog_no_comment; }
     echo "</a></div>\n\n";
 }
 echo "<div class='blog-home-content'>$post[4]</div>\n"; 
 echo "<h2 class='read-more'><a href=\"blog-$post[0]-$post[3]\">$lang_blog_more</a></h2>\n";
 echo "</div>\n";
```

Comment: Adicione o trecho correspondente do HTML no conteúdo da sua pergunta que será mais fácil para alguém conseguir te ajudar. Imagens do *resultado atual* vs *resultado esperado* também são bem vindas.

Comment: Em que browser você tentou?  qual é a fonte que está utilizando?

Comment: estou usando a font arial. e o chrome.

Comment: gente, já resolvi, na tentativa em erro, criei um ".blog-home-content p" e coloquei display:flex; no elemento pai.